# kafka listening on multiple interfaces

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-cluster

I have a requirement as below:
Kafka needs to listen to multiple interfaces, one external and one internal interface. All other components within the system will connect kafka to internal interfaces.
At installation time internal ips on other host are not reachable, need to do some configuration to make them reachable, we do not have control over that. So, assume that when kafka is coming up, internal IPs on other nodes are not reachable to each other.

Scenario:
I have two nodes in cluster:
node1 (External IP: 10.10.10.4, Internal IP: 5.5.5.4)
node2 (External IP: 10.10.10.5, Internal IP: 5.5.5.5)

Now, while installation, 10.10.10.4 can ping to 10.10.10.5 and vice versa, but 5.5.5.4 can not reach to 5.5.5.5. That will happen once kafka installation is done and after that someone does some config to make it reachable, so before kafka installation, we can do make them reachable.

Now the requirement is kafka brokers will exchange the messages on 10.10.10 interface, such that cluster will be formed, but clients will send messages on 5.5.5.X interface.

What I tried was as below:

```
listeners=USERS://0.0.0.0:9092,REPLICATION://0.0.0.0:9093
advertised.listeners=USERS://5.5.5.5:9092,REPLICATION://5.5.5.5:9093
```

Where 5.5.5.5 is the internal ip address.
But with this, while restarting kafka, I see below logs:

```
{"log":"[2020-06-23 19:05:34,923] INFO Creating /brokers/ids/2 (is it secure? false) (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2020-06-23T19:05:34.923403973Z"}
{"log":"[2020-06-23 19:05:34,925] INFO Result of znode creation at /brokers/ids/2 is: OK (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2020-06-23T19:05:34.925237419Z"}
{"log":"[2020-06-23 19:05:34,926] INFO Registered broker 2 at path /brokers/ids/2 with addresses: ArrayBuffer(EndPoint(5.5.5.5,9092,ListenerName(USERS),PLAINTEXT), EndPoint(5.5.5.5,9093,ListenerName(REPLICATION),PLAINTEXT)) (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2020-06-23T19:05:34.926127438Z"}
```

.....

```
{"log":"[2020-06-23 19:05:35,078] INFO Kafka version : 1.1.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2020-06-23T19:05:35.078444509Z"}
{"log":"[2020-06-23 19:05:35,078] INFO Kafka commitId : fdcf75ea326b8e07 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2020-06-23T19:05:35.078471358Z"}
{"log":"[2020-06-23 19:05:35,079] INFO [KafkaServer id=2] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2020-06-23T19:05:35.079436798Z"}
{"log":"[2020-06-23 19:05:35,136] ERROR [KafkaApi-2] Number of alive brokers '0' does not meet the required replication factor '2' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor'). This error can be ignored if the cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet. (kafka.server.KafkaApis)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2020-06-23T19:05:35.136792119Z"}
```

And after that this msg continuously comes up.

```
{"log":"[2020-06-23 19:05:35,166] ERROR [KafkaApi-2] Number of alive brokers '0' does not meet the required replication factor '2' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor'). This error can be ignored if the cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet. (kafka.server.KafkaApis)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2020-06-23T19:05:35.166895344Z"}
```

Is there any way we can achieve that?

With regards,
-M-

Comment: Does this help? https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc If not perhaps you can expand on your question to make it a bit clearer please.

Comment: Thanks for sharing a nice document, Based on the document, I tried above, I modified the qs, but I get the error as mentioned in the qs, can you check if anything else I am missing to include in server.properties.

Comment: Could you clarify your requirement? Using external NIC for inter-broker communication but internal NIC for clients? Are you sure about that?